# Add image to gallery with slug

Tags: gallery

It's possible to create gallery not by id of images, but with url?

I don't want this

```
[gallery ids="729,732,731,720"]
```

I want something like this

```
[gallery slug="http://example.com/wp-uploads/...", "http://example.com/wp-uploads/...", "http://example.com/wp-uploads/..."]
```

Is there some plugin? or anything?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode

By default the gallery shortcode will only accept IDs or if left blank will default to current page.

You need to create a plugin and register your own shortcode or download one that already exists.

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=gallery+load+by+url+wordpress&oq=gallery+load+by+url+wordpress&aqs=chrome..69i57.9981j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8